# How to use IAppBuilder.UseWebApi after OWIN middleware

Tags: katana

I have 3 middleware classes that execute successfully until there are are no more middleware classes. After the middleware classes have been invoked and there are no more I would like to pass the request to the router.

What is the best way of doing this?

For example, I have this code:

```
// Register middleware. Order is important!
app.Use<Authentication>();
app.Use<Logging>();
app.Use<Example>(configExample);
```

This works as expected.On every request first `Authentication` runs, then `Logging`, then `Example`.

And I can see that on starting the program, that these `app.Use<>()` lines instantiate the appropriate middleware by passing in a delegate. That delegate includes a property `Target` which points at the next middleware class to be run. For obvious reasons the delegate passed to the `Example` class is is empty (since it's the last middleware class in the chain).

Without altering code in the last-chained middleware class (I would not like order to be important), how can I invoke the router? My router looks something like this:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    ...
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    ...
);
etc.
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

I think there must be some great logical gap in my understanding since there must be a logical way to end a middleware chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is that the middleware is passed automatically to the controller when there is no more middleware. but the tutorials I was following used lines of code in the middleware that prevented this.

I had followed instructions on a neat way to create middleware here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/864725/ASP-NET-Understanding-OWIN-Katana-and-the-Middlewa.

And these two lines:

```
IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);
await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>Hello from Example " + _configExample + "</h1>");
```

resulted in the response from the controller being truncated (or something). This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Avesta.ASP.Middleware
{
    using AppFunc = Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>;

    public class Example
    {
        AppFunc _next;
        string _configExample;

        public Example(AppFunc next, string configExample)
        {
            _next = next;
            _configExample = configExample;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> env)
        {
            //IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);
            //await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>Hello from Example " + _configExample + "</h1>");
            await _next.Invoke(env);
        }
    }
}
```